# How do I specify which routing file Symfony should use with multiple Kernels

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I am writing a Symfony test application where I have an AdminKernel and a ShopKernel so I can have different portals. They both have different routing files because I don't want users being able to go to the admin pages. I don't want to use `if is_granted()` in my twig files because I want both the admin panel and the shop to run on different ports on my server (in test setup 80 for my shop, and 8080 for my admin page, as there will be a proxy in front of the application in the end that will get request from the vhost based on port, while there may be several domain names).

I got all of that working but when I test the routing the shop is able to go to the admin panel even though they shouldn't be.

When I debug the routes it shows the correct routes.

When I type `php bin/console debug:router product_show`, which is an admin page in my ShopKernel it says: `The route "product_show" does not exist.` which is good.

And in the AdminKernel it also works as expected, returning the route: `/product/{id}/show/`.

But when I try to go to the shop page in the browser and I type `localhost:80/product/9/show` it shows the page while it shouldn't.

It takes quite a long time for Symfony to load the page so I suspect Symfony tries to find the route, but can't and then resorts to using the routing file I used for the Admin page but I'm not sure. Could anyone assist me with this, as I've tried to find a solution already but I just can't see why the routes of a different kernel are loaded.

This is my ShopKernel:

```
class ShopKernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    private const CONFIG_EXTS = '.{php,xml,yaml,yml}';

    public function registerBundles(): iterable
    {
        $contents = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php';
        foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
            if ($envs[$this->environment] ?? $envs['all'] ?? false) {
                yield new $class();
            }
        }
    }

    public function getProjectDir(): string
    {
        return \dirname(__DIR__);
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader): void
    {
        $container->addResource(new FileResource($this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php'));
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', \PHP_VERSION_ID < 70400 || $this->debug);
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_factories', true);
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

        $loader->load($confDir.'/packages/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/packages/'.$this->environment.'/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/services'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/services_'.$this->environment.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');

    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes): void
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config/portal/shop/';

        $routes->import($confDir.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        $routes->import($confDir.'routes.yaml', '/', 'glob');
    }
}
```

and this is my AdminKernel:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;



class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    private const CONFIG_EXTS = '.{php,xml,yaml,yml}';

    public function registerBundles(): iterable
    {
        $contents = require $this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php';
        foreach ($contents as $class => $envs) {
            if ($envs[$this->environment] ?? $envs['all'] ?? false) {
                yield new $class();
            }
        }
    }

    public function getProjectDir(): string
    {
        return \dirname(__DIR__);
    }

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerBuilder $container, LoaderInterface $loader): void
    {
        $container->addResource(new FileResource($this->getProjectDir().'/config/bundles.php'));
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', \PHP_VERSION_ID < 70400 || $this->debug);
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_factories', true);
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

        $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
        $loader->load($confDir.'/{services}_'.$this->environment.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes): void
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

        $routeDir = "../public/admin/";

        $routes->import($confDir.'/portal/admin/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        $routes->import($confDir.'/portal/admin/'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
    }
}
```

this is my admin routes.yaml:

```
product_index:
   path: /
   controller: App\Controller\ProductController::index

product_new:
   path: /product/new/
   controller: App\Controller\ProductController::new

product_edit:
   path: /product/{id}/edit/
   controller: App\Controller\ProductController::edit

product_show:
   path: /product/{id}/show/
   controller: App\Controller\ProductController::show

product_delete:
   path: /product/{id}/delete/
   controller: App\Controller\ProductController::delete

fos_user_security_login:
   path: /login/
   defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

fos_user_security_check:
   path: /login_check/
   defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

fos_user_security_logout:
   path: /logout/
   defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
```

and my shop routes.yaml:

```
index:
   path: /
   controller: App\Controller\ProductController::index

product_bestel:
  path: /product/{id}/bestel
  controller: App\Controller\ProductController::addtocart

product_checkout:
   path: /product/checkout
   controller: App\Controller\ProductController::checkout

fos_user_security_login:
   path: /login/
   defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

fos_user_security_check:
   path: /login_check/
   defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:check }

fos_user_security_logout:
   path: /logout/
   defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:logout }
```

So how can I stop Symfony from reading the other routing file?

Comment: The kernel is instantiated on `index.php`. So if you what want to instantiate a different one, you should look there.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have two index.php files both in different folders. One for the shop and one for the admin panel. each calling the correct Kernel

Comment: You also have different var directories for each kernel?  Because routes are cached.  Seems like you are making things harder than they have to be.  Couple of Symfony firewalls should take care of things.Or just make two independent Symfony projects.